# Pass reflection method as argument (functional interface)

Tags: java, reflection, functional-interface

I have the below functional interface

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Processor { void handle(String text); }
```

I have a method

```java
doSomething(Processor processor)
```

I can call doSomething like this

```java
public class Demo {
    public void rockTheWorldTest(String text) {
    // Processing 
    }
}
```

I can call it like below

```java
doSomething(new Demo::rockTheWorldTest);
```

But I wont be able to know the name of the method in a particular class and I want to call this using the reflection from another class

```java
Method[] testClasMethods = DemoAbstractOrchestratorTest.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
for (Method method : testClasMethods) {
   doSomething(method) // Not able to do this.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the circumstances nor the context that led you to take this approach, but a way of doing it would be:

(assuming you are looping over `Demo.class.getDeclaredMethods()`)

```
doSomething((text) -> {
        try {
                method.invoke(new Demo(), text);

        } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
});
```

which is equivalent more or less to the call `doSomething(new Demo()::rockTheWorldTest);` when `method` is exactly `rockTheWorldTest`, in fact, I think you have to make sure that `method`'s signature "matches" the one of `void handle(String text)`. I would filter `testClasMethods` before doing the "invocation" loop leaving just the methods that matches.